# Can we delete the cloudformation file after migrating to the cdk?

Tags: aws-cdk

We're looking at migrating our toolchain to using the CDk. We currently use cloudformation files to generate stacks for our various apps.

For a given app, we currently have the following structure:

```
|- cloudformation/
  |- cloudformation.json
|- src/
```

We want to be able to use the same cloudfromation stack but remove the `cloudformation.json` file.

Looking at this: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/migrating-cloudformation-templates-to-the-aws-cloud-development-kit/

It seems that the preferred way to migrate to using the cdk for a given app is to keep the cloudformation file and import it into the cdk. Then any new changes we need to make are done in the cdk stack.

I tried the instructions in the blog post, but when I went to delete the old cloudformation file, it wouldn't work(obviously).

Is there a way to delete the cloudformation file? Or is the expectations for migrating to the cdk that the cloudformation file sticks around?

Answer (score 1):

The suggestion seems to be to abandon your old git project and maintain things in new one. Is that hard for your use case?

Comment: yeah, we have multiple projects that are years old. Right now we're looking at the trade offs between keep around the "old" cloudformation stack(just importing cloudformation.json into the cdk) and creaking a new stack that's just using the CDK.